# How to return this in method

Tags: c++

I have a class Image, and I need to return instance of this class. What's the simplies way to do it? I'm a java programmer and "return this" giving me an error.

```
#include <string>
#include "AEEImage.h"

using namespace std;

IImage *image;
Image *img;

Image::Image()
{
    image = new IImage();
}

Image::~Image()
{
    delete image;
    image = NULL;
}

 Image *createImage(string str)
{
    return /*return instance of this class*/;
}
```

Here's definition of Image:

```
#pragma once

#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Image
{
public:
    Image();
    ~Image();
    Image createImage(string str);
    Image createImage(const Image *img, int x, int y, int with, int height, int transform);
    Image createImage(istream is);
};
```

I have to write a class in C++ similiar to Image class in JAVA ME ([link](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Image.html)):
-these same name of class (Image)
-these same name of methods, type of arguments and return types

Comment: Forget Java, get [a good book](http://tinyurl.com/so-cxxbooks), read it, and come back afterwards.

Comment: Please, post a class declaration. And what are you using global variables for?..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`this` is only available in non-static member functions; they are called on an object, and `this` points to that object. `createImage()` is a non-member function; it's not called on an object, and so there is no `this` pointer.

Presumably, it's supposed to create an image and return a pointer to that. Perhaps you want:

```
return new Image;
```

Remember that it's the caller's responsibility to `delete` the object once it's no longer needed - there is no garbage collection in C++. You would be wise to study [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) to learn how to automatically manage dynamic objects in C++; in particular, a smart pointer would do the trick here:

```
std::unique_ptr<Image> createImage() {
    return std::unique_ptr<Image>(new Image);
}
```

In general, you should forget any idioms you learned in Java, since that is a very different language. There are [many good books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) on C++.

You should also avoid global variables, especially for things that logically belong to an instance of a class. It looks very much like `IImage *image;` should be a member of `Image` rather than a global variable (although perhaps it already is; I can't tell, since you haven't posted the definition of `Image`).

UPDATE: you now say that `createImage` is a member, and that the class should emulate the Java class you link to. In that case, it should be `static`. For a class member, that has roughly the same meaning that it does in Java: it is associated with the class itself, not any particular object. Then the definition needs to qualify the name with `Image::` to indicate that it is a member, not a different function declared in the namespace. So you want something like:

```
class Image {
public:
    // some members
    static Image * createImage(string); // Add "static" to match the Java class.
                                        // Return a pointer (or a smart pointer)
};

Image * Image::createImage(string) {    // Add "Image::" to indicate it's a member
    return new Image;
}

// Usage example:
Image * image = Image::createImage("whatever");  // "::" rather than Java's "."
```

Note that returning `Image` rather than `Image *` (or a smart pointer) will return a *copy* of the `Image` object, which is (probably) not what you want; that's another big difference from Java, where class objects are always passed by reference(*). Pointers are the closest things that C++ has to Java's object references.

(*) Note to pedants: by "passed by reference", I mean the object itself is not cloned; the object reference is passed by value.

Comment: In Java, Objects are NEVER passed by reference. They are always passed by value. So many people get this wrong. Please read [PassByValue](http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm).

Comment: @MWid: Yes, I know that Java's object references are passed by value; I was using "pass by reference" to mean that the objects themselves are never cloned, as they are in C++.

Answer (score 4):

You've declared that function as a free one when it needs to be a member function. Only member functions have a `this` pointer.

```
class image {
   //...
   Image *createImage(string str)
   //...
};

Image *Image::createImage(string str)
{
    return this;
}
```

Although if it's a create function your logic is probably wrong and you shouldn't be using `this`.

Answer (score 2):

First, createImage(..) has to be a member function of class Image, as mentioned before.
Second, there are three ways to return the current object, by pointer, by reference and by value:

```
class Image
{
    public:

    //by Pointer
    Image* PointerToImage()
    {
        return this;
    }
    const Image* ConstPointerToImage() const
    {
        return this;
    }
    //by Reference
    Image& ReferenceToImage()
    {
        return *this;
    }
    const Image& ReferenceToImage() const
    {
        return *this;
    }
    //by Value
    Image CopyOfImage() const
    {
        reuturn *this;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to return the instance, you already have it when you call createImage?

Comment: `createImage` isn't a member of `Image`.